# Como Configurar Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabbarcontroller

Possuo uma Tab Bar Controller com 5 ViewControllers ligada a ela.

Com isso, são exibidos 5 botões na barra. Gostaria que a ViewController ligada ao terceiro botão (botão do meio) seja a primeira a ser exibida quando a tela for aberta.

Realizei a construção dela pelo Storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo storyboard você não vai conseguir selecionar outro item. Sugiro você seleciona-lo por código, quando a aplicação é lançada, no `- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` com o código abaixo:

```
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UIViewController *terceiroViewController = tabController.viewControllers[2]; // Indice do VC desejado
tabController.selectedViewController = terceiroViewController;
```

Answer (score 1):

Como sua Tab Bar Controller vai chamar a primeira tela que está ligada a ela automaticamente basta por esse código no `viewDidLoad()` da primeira tela:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //como são 5 botões o index do terceiro é 2.
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2; 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As duas respostas são ótimas! E ajudaram. Mas há algumas observações que acho interessante fazer. A solução de @DouglasFerreira,  fazer uma nova instancia de objetos já criados pelo Storyboard. E como tenho algumas telas antes de carregar a TabBarController, então não iria atuar no objeto correto.

A solução apresentada por @iTSangar não funcionou pois o objeto não respondeu ao apontamento direto na variável `selectedIndex`.

A solução que criei foi a seguinte:

Criei uma classe controller e liguei ela com a TabBarController no Storyboar, e no método
 `viewDidLoad`, como recomendado por @iTSangar, fiz isso:

```
[self setSelectedIndex:2];
```

E funcionou!!