# Tela inicial no storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, iphone

Estou utilizando o Xcode para o desenvolvimento de um app.

Nele utilizo o `storyboard` para as telas. Suponhamos que a estrutura de telas seja a seguinte:

Possuo 5 telas sequenciais, a qual uma leva à próxima, até chegar na quinta (última) tela. A minha tela inicial, definida via storyboard é a tela de número 1. Para navegação, tenho uma `UINavigationController`.

Gostaria de saber como eu posso iniciar o app em outra tela, de maneira a qual eu não perca a navegação entre as demais. Para melhor exemplificar:
Iniciar na tela 4, mas poder retornar para a tela 3 ou seguir para a tela 5.

*Obs.: O código pode ser em Swift ou Objective-C.*

Comment: Pode colocar o código que ta usando no seu main?

Comment: Na verdade no AppDelegate está o código padrão, criado pelo Xcode. Não realizei nenhuma alteração

Comment: Eu programei há uns anos atras com Xcode... não tem um inicializador que você fala a View que vai abrir?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Quando se cria e defini a UIViewController inicial via storyboard, ele faz tudo isso implícito. Há como eu deixar sem controladora inicial, e definir isso na maneira quando for inicializar o app, mas assim eu perco a referencia de navegação para a tela 3, devido ela não estar alocada na memória.

Comment: @Gian http://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1 estes exemplos podem te dar uma luz

Answer (score 1):

**O que você pode fazer é criar a pilha de Views programaticamente pelo AppDelegate.**

> Nunca tentei criar toda a pilha dinamicamente, apenas alterei a já
>   existente. Não tenho como testar no momento, então não garanto que irá
>   funcionar, mas é um caminho.

**Segue implementação:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let tela_1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tela_1") as! UIViewController
    let tela_1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tela_2") as! UIViewController
    let tela_3 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tela_3") as! UIViewController
    let tela_4 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tela_4") as! UIViewController
    let tela_5 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tela_5") as! UIViewController

    let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UINavigationController
    navigationController.viewControllers = [tela_1, tela_2, tela_3, tela_4, tela_5]

    self.window?.rootViewController = tela_4
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Obs.: Não esqueça de trocar "tela_N" pelo nome de suas classes de fato.

Comment: Sua resposta não terá o efeito desejado já que você define como `rootViewController` a tela_4 e não o `navigationController`. E no caso de ser apenas um erro de digitiação o array de `viewControllers` deveria ser `[tela_1, tela_2, tela_3, tela4]` assim a tela_4 é a que estará no topo da pilha.

Answer (score -1):

Não sei qual é o contexto do seu app, mas esse tipo de navegação não parece ter muita usabilidade. Dando uma olhada no [Guia de Interface Humana do iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH66-SW1)  no tópico de [UI Elements - Tab Bar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW52):

[image: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Art/music_tab_bar_iphone_2x.png]

> A tab bar gives people the ability to switch between different subtasks, views, or modes in an app.

Então usando `Tab Bar` você pode ter esse controle das suas 5 telas de modo que a navegação entre eles fique mais intuitiva.

No caso de como começar de uma tela específica (*tela 4 por exemplo*) [dê uma olhada nessa pergunta aqui do stackoverflow em português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60964/como-configurar-tab-bar-controller/61031#61031)